# Oracle simple list results to comma separated list with quotes?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to get results of this simple query

```sql
select PersonID from Persons where city ='Miami'
```

as a flat comma separated list with quotes.

desired results should be **'3','5','7','8'**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/95e86d/1/0

I tried list_add but im getting: `ORA-00904: "STRING_AGG": invalid identifier`

```sql
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID NUMBER,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
    
    
      
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, FirstName, City)
  VALUES (1, 'Tom B.','Stavanger');
    
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, FirstName, City)
  VALUES (2, 'Jerry M.','Train City');
    
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, FirstName, City)
  VALUES (3, 'Eric g.','Miami');
      
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, FirstName, City)
  VALUES (4, 'Bar Y.','Manhattan');
      
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, FirstName, City)
  VALUES (5, 'John K.','Miami');
      
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, FirstName, City)
  VALUES (6, 'Foo F.','Washington');
      
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, FirstName, City)
  VALUES (7, 'Alen D.','Miami');
      
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, FirstName, City)
  VALUES (8, 'John K.','Miami');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select listagg( '''' || PersonID || '''', ',' ) 
         within group (order by personID) 
  from Persons 
 where city ='Miami'
```

should work.

I'd have to question why you're trying to produce this particular result.  If you're going to generate this string so that you can subsequently use it in the `IN` list of another dynamically generated SQL statement, you're probably better off taking a step back because there are much better ways to solve the problem.

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/95e86d/5)

Comment: Thank you Justin, Yes I need it in another query IN clause but I need to do two actions that's why I need the physical list.

Comment: This is throwing an error ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long 
                         - > 
I think its not considering the where clause.  so i guess ill have to consider another strategy

Comment: @JavaSheriff - `listagg` doesn't support CLOBs.  You could write a custom aggregate function that produces a CLOB.  But taking a step back, why do you need to do this in two steps?  It is generally vastly more efficient to simply embed your query in the `IN` list of the query you actually want to run.

Comment: Its some data issue, I have to keep the list, update to value A, run some external process, then run the update again on to value B    it seems like your solution the where clause doesn't filter when it first aggregates is that correct?  aggregation happening before the where? i don't have so many records (after the where) so im not sure why is it throwing ORA-01489

Comment: @JavaSheriff - The error indicates that the result of `listagg` exceeds 4000 bytes after filtering.  If `PersonID` is, say, 5 bytes long and you're adding two single quotes and a comma, that would be 8 bytes so if the query returns more than 500 rows you'd exceed the limit.  Fetching a comma-separated list back to Java in order to dynamically assemble subsequent SQL statements is generally an inefficient way to build any sort of recurring process.